# Can you swim underwater in Hogwarts Legacy?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

I know you can swim in Hogwarts Legacy, but can you swim underwater somewhere in the game or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Kind of**.

**Hogwarts Legacy doesn't allow you to dive freely**, i.e. you can't go underwater in any chosen place, even if it's a deep reservoir.

**Your character can only dive near small whirlpools**:

[image: Hogwarts Legacy Water whirlpool]

When you dive near these small whirlpools, then you're searching and finding random loot that you can then equip or sell. In some cases, diving is also used to find quest items.